# MySQL keeps complaining about foreign key. Error 150

Tags: mysql, sql, database, foreign-keys

I'm trying to create a table with a foreign key to itself. I want to model a category that can be a child of another category. Here is my SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `recipes`.`category` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL COMMENT '',
  `name` VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL COMMENT '',
  `description` VARCHAR(255) NULL COMMENT 'Description of the recipe category.',
  `parent_id` INT NULL COMMENT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)  COMMENT '',
  CONSTRAINT `parent_id`
    FOREIGN KEY (`id`)
    REFERENCES `recipes`.`category` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION);
```

However, MySQL keeps giving me an error:

> Can't create table 'recipes.category' (errno: 150)

I'm trying to find out what I'm doing wrong, can anyone give me a hint? Docs say that:

> Cannot create table. If the error message refers to error 150, table
>   creation failed because a foreign key constraint was not correctly
>   formed.

However, this does not help me much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess that you want `parent_id` column link with a foreign key to the `id` column (*instead of `id` column to `id` column*) to build a hierarchy structure. Otherwise it doesn't make much sense:

```
constraint `parent_id`
foreign key (`parent_id`)
references `category` (`id`)
on delete no action
on update no action);
```

[**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/42959)